Ethers v6 TypeError: overflow
I'm trying to parse some ETH amounts to display them on client side, using ethers v6.11.1 but I get this error. The same code used to work fine with ethers v5, I have checked the type of value, and it is string.
const parseAmount = (value: string): number => {
  return ethers.toNumber(value) * 10 ** -18;
};

Error:

TypeError: overflow (argument="value", value=21150000000000000, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.11.1)


Fixed by using the method formatEther.
const parseAmount = (value: string): number => {
  return Number(ethers.formatEther(value));
};

